# Adding HTML from an external file to a Page Viewer Web Part on SharePoint

Tags: html, sharepoint, iframe

I'm trying to add HTML from an external file into a .htm file that is being added to SharePoint using a 'Page Viewer' Web Part.

It needs to support IE7 - The best way I could think of was to use an iFrame... but the page viewer Web Part is an iFrame itself; I'm guessing nested iFrames can't be done as I cant find a way to make this work. I tired using the 'object' tag too but that didn't work, PHP isn't an option either :(

Are there any alternative ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `Content Editor Webpart`.

Steps to add `Content Editor Webpart`

1. Edit that page
2. click on Add a WebPart
3. select `Media and Content`

Inside content editor webpart paste your contents like this

```
<iframe id="iframe1" height="900" width="800" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="paste your url here"></iframe>
```

Hope this will help?

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion! I had been hoping to keep the two sets of html is separate files but this does work so I think it may be the easiest way to achieve this. Thank you :)

Comment: Haven't used it in a while. The Content Editor Web Part can also link to another file (within SharePoint)